# Set ldconfig LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a docker container

Tags: docker, ld

I have a docker container which I use to build software and generate shared libraries in. I would like to use those libraries in another docker container for actually running applications. To do this, I am using the build docker with a mounted volume to have those libraries on the host machine.

My docker file for the RUNTIME container looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt update
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /build/dist/lib
RUN ldconfig
WORKDIR /build
```

and when I run with the following:

```
docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) -it -v $(realpath .):/build runtime_docker bash
```

I do not see any of the libraries from /build/dist/lib in the ldconfig -p cache.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The bind-mounted volumes from the host (when you use the `-v` flag) are only read once the container is running. During the build stage when `ldconfig` is run, `/build` will be empty. Could that be the issue? Possibly you could run `ldconfig` as a `CMD`, which is executed at runtime when your volumes are actually mounted. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting how you're expecting this to work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to `COPY` the libraries into the image before you `RUN ldconfig`; volumes won't help you here.

Remember that first you run a `docker build` command.  That runs all of the commands in the Dockerfile, without any volumes mounted.  Then you take that image and `docker run` a container from it.  Volume mounts only happen when the `docker run` happens, but the `RUN ldconfig` has already happened.

In your Dockerfile, you should `COPY` the files into the image.  There's no particular reason to not use the "normal" system directories, since the image has an isolated filesystem.

```sh
FROM openjdk:8

# Copy shared-library dependencies in
COPY dist/lib/libsomething.so.1 /usr/lib
RUN ldconfig

# Copy the actual binary to run in and set it as the default container command
COPY dist/bin/something /usr/bin
CMD ["something"]
```

Comment: Ok that's helpful and I follow that. Do I need to run docker build every time I update those libraries for this scheme to work? Edit: To be clear, I had considered this before, but I thought if there was a way to do this with `docker run`, when I edit the library files, I could just `docker run` the second container without having the rebuild it. It seems like with this method, I need to rebuild the container every time to ensure the copy happens with updates lib files.

Comment: You do need to re-run `docker build`, in the same way you need to run some build process to create the `.so` files and presumably your Java `.jar` files.

Answer (score 2):

If your shared libraries are only available at container run-time, the conventional solution (as far as I can tell) would be to include the `ldconfig` command in a startup script, and use the dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` directive to make your runtime container execute this script every time the container runs.

This should achieve your desired behaviour, and (I think) should avoid needing to generate a new container image every time you rebuild your code. This is slightly different from the common Docker use case of generating a new image for every build by running `docker build` at build-time, but I think it's a perfectly valid use case, and quite compatible with the way Docker works. Docker has historically been used as a CI/CD tool to streamline post-build workflows, but it is increasingly being used for other things, such as the build step itself. This naturally means people are coming up with slightly different ways of using Docker to facilitate various new and different types of workflow.